# PhoneGap plugin for ios returning FAILED pluginJSON

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

I'm working on a Phonegap/Cordova(version 2.9.0) custom plugin creation for iOS app. My steps are as follows :

1. I created a HelloPlugin.js file and copy it under www/js/ folder, its having code :

   ```
   var HelloPlugin =
   {
     callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType)
     {
       alert('a');
       return Cordova.exec( success, fail, "HelloPlugin", "nativeFunction", ['1']);
     }
   };
   ```
2. I created HelloPlugin.h and HelloPlugin.m files under plugins folder, code :

   ```
   // .h
   #import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

   @interface HelloPlugin : CDVPlugin

   - (void)nativeFunction:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

   @end

   // .m

   #import "HelloPlugin.h"

   @implementation HelloPlugin

   - (void)nativeFunction:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
   {
     NSLog(@"Hello, this is a native function called from PhoneGap/Cordova!");
   }

   @end
   ```
3. I added following code to config.xml file :

   ```
   <feature name="HelloPlugin">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVPlugin"/>
   </feature>
   ```
4. At last I modified index.html in following way :

   1. Script reference added. ()
   2. JS code added :

      ```
        function callNativePlugin(returnSuccess) 
        {
           HelloPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
        }

        function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
              alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
        }

        function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
              alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
        }
      ```
   3. Two buttons added and function called:

      "callNativePlugin('success');"
      "callNativePlugin('error');"

I hope this is the only required things I need to do for activating plugin.

Issue : While running the app, I am getting FAILED pluginJSON error on console.

Output :

-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "HelloPlugin2650437",
  "HelloPlugin",
  "nativeFunction",
  [
    "1",
    "1",
    "1"
  ]
]

What mistake I have done, please let me know. I really Appreciate your efforts. Please help me here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing that jumped out is your plugin package name.  It should be your iOS class name which is "HelloPlugin".

```
  <param name="ios-package" value="HelloPlugin"/>
```

One of the purpose of the new way of referencing plugin is to allow flexibility and backward compatibility of plugin names especially on Android.  Example:

```
<feature name="HelloPlugin">
  <param name="ios-package" value="HelloCDVPlugin"/>
  <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.HelloCDVPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

Where "HelloCDVPlugin" is your iOS class name and "com.phonegap.plugins.HelloCDVPlugin" is your Android class name.

Comment: Worked for me thanks a lot. I was working with multiple versions of Cordova which gave me this issue for the same plugin.

Comment: @LalitPaliwal hello lalit Sundeep sharma from noida I join Hiteshi with Vijay yadav  ,hope you remember. I am facing same problem wat to do .

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for js

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/hello",
function (require, exports, module) {

var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function greet(name, win, fail) {
  exec(win, fail, "Hello",
      "greet", [name]);
}

module.exports = {
  greet: greet
}
}
);
```

and change cordova.exec to

```
exec(this.callbacks.onSuccess, this.callbacks.onError, "Hello", "greet", [defaults]);
```

You can find example from below link

https://github.com/cristobal/phonegap-ios-datepicker-plugin

You have to modify the code as per your requirement.